# Verifying Gram-Schmidt Algorithm with Mathematica

Tags: linear-algebra, complex

According to a review of the Graham-Schmidt alogirithm in my textbook:

> [image]

This is only the first part of the procedure, but it's what I'm focused on for this post.  I attempted to verify that $\langle 1 | 2' \rangle$ with Mathematica using complex vectors

$$
| I \rangle = (e^{(x i 2 \pi)}, 0) \\
| II \rangle = (0.2 i,e^{(I*3 \pi / 4)})
$$

as $x$ ranges from $0$ to $1$.

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{one, ii, twoish},
  one = {E^(x*I*2*Pi), 0} ;
  
  ii = {0.2 I, E^(I*3 Pi/4)};
  twoish = ii - (Conjugate[one].ii)*one;
  ComplexListPlot[{Conjugate[one].twoish}]
  ], {x, 0, 1}]
```

Sliding `x` around seems to show many counter-examples to the final result being zero.  For example:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: This is a consequence of floating-point arithmetic (i.e. numerical error). Placing the result in `Chop[]` removes these small errors. Or equivalently, replace 0.2 with 1/5 and x with `Rationalize[x,0]` to work with exact numbers.